# Create a Simulator Build for facebook app review. (No bundle URL present)

Tags: react-native, facebook-app-requests

I'm preparing for submitting build file for facebook app review.

I created simulator build file. but when I verify build with this command,

```
ios-sim launch /path/to/your-app.app
```

It said No bundle URL present.

It's working well with xcode.

There's no problem at all without this.

but only this simulator build file is not working with above commmand.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this with very simple change.

There's one thing facebook didn't say about this.

It should be release mode when you create build file.

Don't forget about this and waste your time.